# FTP client Failed on UBUNTU but working fine on Windows 7

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I am stuck on an issue that while I deploy warr on Windows and use ftp client to transfer file its working fine.

Windows log screen shot:

[image]

but when I deploy same warr on Ubuntu 14.04 its through exception that spring failed to create FTP client and Failed to execute on session
Ubuntu log screen shot:

[image]

using tomcat7

Answer (score 0):

"530 Login incorrect" means that the FTP username/password combination is incorrect.  Are you sure that you are using the same username and password on Ubuntu that you used on Windows?

Comment: Yes same configuration .. our application working fine on windows7 but when I deploy on ubuntu 14.4 FTP session failed and application can't write file on folder